# How can a function convert its printf-style (fmt, args, ...) input args into a single string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can a python 2.7 def input log.debug style arguments (ie. printf-style) and then turn the args into a single string?

I have a body of code that does a lot of `log.debug(fmt, args, ...)`.

I want to turn the input args `fmt, args, ...`  into a single string.

For example:
Presently, this does a standard debug log from 1 format arg and 3 arg values:

```
self.log.debug("Setting parameter %s(%d) to: %d", axis_params[param]['desc1'], param, value)
```

..which logs:  "Setting parameter "

But, in my function:

```
self.grabit.debug("Setting parameter %s(%d) to: %d",
                  axis_params[param]['desc1'], param, value)
```

...I want `grabit` to generate a string that contains: "Setting parameter val1(val2) to: val3>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just splat the args using the `*` [unpacking syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and use the `%` operator to format a string.  Assuming that `self.grabit` is an instance of a hypothetical `Grabit` class, the code would look something like this:

```
class Grabit(object):
    def debug(self, fmt, *args):
        return fmt % args
```